Could not convert PHP value of type DateTimeImmutable to type Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType
I have a Symfony Command that reads rows from a spreadsheet and inserts them into a MySQL table. The command was working fine in Symfony 4.4. I started getting this error after I upgraded my version of Symfony and PHP.
Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Exception\InvalidType: Could not convert PHP value of type DateTimeImmutable to type Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime.

This is the code that seems to be throwing the error
$accountstatement->setAccountStatementCreatedOn(new \DateTimeImmutable());
$em->persist($accountstatement);
$em->flush();

The Symfony Code for the entity which maps to the mysql Database
#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
private $AccountStatement_CreatedOn;
.
.
.
public function getAccountStatementCreatedOn(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->AccountStatement_CreatedOn;
    }

public function setAccountStatementCreatedOn(\DateTimeInterface $AccountStatement_CreatedOn): self
    {
        $this->AccountStatement_CreatedOn = $AccountStatement_CreatedOn;

        return $this;
    }

My Stack versions:
Symfony : 6.4.9
PHP     : 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18
doctrine/dbal                       4.0.4
doctrine/deprecations               1.1.3
doctrine/doctrine-bundle            2.12.0
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle   3.6.1
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.3.1
doctrine/event-manager              2.0.1
doctrine/inflector                  2.0.10
doctrine/instantiator               2.0.0
doctrine/lexer                      3.0.1
doctrine/migrations                 3.8.0
doctrine/orm                        3.2.1
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.18-MariaDB
There are a few questions on Stackoverflow with the similar issue but the root causes in those cases are different and hence doesn't resolve my issue. Wonder if anyone can point out what could be wrong.

It would be far more useful if you show us the code that is causing this error

For PHP DateTimeImmutable, you should use Doctrine datetime_immutable  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/4.0/reference/types.html#datetime_immutable

Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime - did you check whether using DateTime would work?

@RiggsFolly I have edited the question and included a snippet of code that I think is causing the problem

Well as you are passing a new object to that method call (i.e. containing no existing data) , why not pass new \DateTime() as that is what it is expecting

@RiggsFolly Will try it out. But then this piece of code and several others with DateTimeImmutable() was working wonder why it stopped after the upgrade.

Look at the function definition, and the upgrade notes. At a guess the function prototype has been changed in the newer version

"included a snippet of code" - the snippet is missing the configuration for the column you want to use

@RiggsFolly I have included the entity code

Did you try to use any of the suggestions given in the comments?

have you update doctrine/orm from 2.x to 3.x?

You are using the wrong type, or the wrong value. Either set the db type to datetime_immutable, or pass a new DateTime(). The error is descriptive enough, IMO.

@RiggsFolly I think you were the closest. "
Passing instances of DateTimeImmutable to this type is deprecated since 3.7." as per the doctrine page at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/4.0/reference/types.html#datetime_immutablethe. Please post your answer I will accept it.
NicoHaase I tried the suggestion by RiggsFolly and used "new \DateTime" nd it works
